# How to go about finding a transformation $T$ in order to solve an integral.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, transformation

I have the integral 
$$\int\int_R\left(2x+y\right)dA$$
Where $R$ is the region bounded by 
$$x+y=-1, x+y = 3, 2x=y,2x-4=y$$
So my first though was drawing the region, which gave me this odd region, so I thought I'd probably need to apply a transformation. My problem in this process is going about finding the appropriate transformation.

The transformation ended up being 
$$u = x+y, v = 2x-y$$
Which led to me getting 
$$u+v=3x\rightarrow x = \frac{1}{3}(u+v)$$
Using that value of $x$
$$u = \frac{1}{3}(u+v)+y\rightarrow y = \frac{1}{3}(2u-v)$$
So that process gave me $x = \frac{1}{3}(u+v)$ and $y = \frac{1}{3}(2u-v)$.

And after applying the constraints of the region to see my bounds of $u$ and $v$, and finding the Jacobian, simplified the integral greatly.

So my question is, is there a process for finding the transformation needed to simplify, or is it all trial and error, which is how I solved this problem.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure generalizes to linear transformations aand regions enclosed by parallelograms.   You map mapped the lines with slope -1 to vertical lines (in the uv plane) and lines of slope 2 to horizontal lines.       In general, the transformations are ad hoc.   However, there a coordinate systems and transformation that are adapted to various type of regions.  For example, the polar coordinate conversion for $\int\int_D xy  \ dx \, dy,$ where $D$ is the annulus $1\leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 4,$   is easily converted to an integral in "box" in $(r,\theta)$ space:
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^2_1  r^3 \cos \theta \sin \theta \ dr \ d\theta 
$$